# Given list of strings return just strings not contained in any other

Tags: python, string, list, search, set

I'm trying to find a computationally friendly way for doing the following:

given `list_of_strings = ['many', 'man', 'cat', 'caterpillar', 'pillow', 'pi', 'pill']`

return `sublist = ['many', 'caterpillar', 'pillow']`, i.e. the list of strings not contained in any other string.

The simplest solution would be to iterate over the elements and check whether each element is contained in the other, with O(n^2) complexity (even if there are some little optimizations I thought about, like sorting the strings by length,  but this adds the sorting complexity), but I think it's too expensive.

I thought also about implementing a trie and then use each element of the list as an haystack, then keeping just the strings contained in one haystack (that of the string itself).

I think I'm missing more than I know, so I'm looking for suggestions

Comment: Are there any duplicates in your list?

Comment: @IoaTzimas nope, already unique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented the following (but I'm eager to see other approaches before accepting any answer):

```
import ahocorasick

def make_automation(list_of_tokens):
    A = ahocorasick.Automaton()
    for idx, key in enumerate(list_of_tokens):
        A.add_word(key, (idx, key))
    A.make_automaton()
    return A

def search_list_aho_corasick(txt_to_search, ahocorasick_automaton):
    match = []
    for end_index, (insert_order, original_value) in ahocorasick_automaton.iter(txt_to_search):
        start_index = end_index - len(original_value) + 1
        if original_value == txt_to_search:
            continue
        else:
            match.append(original_value) 
        assert txt_to_search[start_index:start_index + len(original_value)] == original_value
    return match

def filter_matches(list_of_matches):
    if len(list_of_matches) == 0:
        return list_of_matches
    else:
        aut = make_automation(list_of_matches)
        contained = []
        contained_result = list(map(lambda x: search_list_aho_corasick(x, aut), list_of_matches))
        return list(set(list_of_matches) - set(flatten_list(contained_result)))
```

So in our case:

```
result = filter_matches(list_of_strings)
```

It uses [ahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/) package, which implements Aho-Corasick algorithm for string search.

Compared to @IoaTzimas answers it drastically reduces computation time: I've backtested both on a 40k list and it went from roughly 330seconds to less than a second

Answer (score 1):

The following should work considering that there are no duplicates in your list (if there are, question must clarify what will happen with them and the code can be adjusted):

```
def splt(word): 
    m=[]
    for i in range(1,len(word)+1):
        for k in range(len(word)-i+1):
            m.append(word[k:k+i])
    return m

d={}

for i in list_of_strings:
    for k in splt(i):
        if k in d:
            d[k]+=1
        else:
            d[k]=1

p=[i for i in d if d[i]==1]

result=[i for i in p if i in list_of_strings]
```

Output:

```
print(result):

['many', 'caterpillar', 'pillow']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I would like to benchmark mine against yours and select the best one based on those results :)